# Help solve for length $PQ$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]how do I approach this question using simultaneous equations with trig and or pythag??? Solve for length $PQ$

Cheers bob

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: It is above in picture

Comment: Hard to read and way too much white space.

Comment: Not only hard to read as it was pretty badly scanned: either there is no $\;Q\;$ at all in the picture or else it is pretty hidden...

Comment: @Timbuc $Q$ is clearly at the bottom left.

Comment: "Clearly"? I could have sworn that is an "O" ...

Comment: Picture quality is low

Comment: Any answers the bottom left is a q

Answer (score 3):

Let $PQ=x$ and $QS=y$

Then for triangle $PQS$:
$$x^2 +y^2 = 12^2$$
$$x^2+y^2 = 144$$

For triangle PTR:
$$(x-2)^2+y^2=11^2$$
$$x^2-4x+4+y^2=121$$
So adding $23$ to both sides:
$$x^2-4x+4+y^2+23=121+23$$
$$x^2-4x+27+y^2=144$$
So
$$x^2-4x+27+y^2 = x^2+y^2$$
Take $x^2+y^2$ from both sides
$$-4x+27=0$$
$$4x=27$$
$$x=\frac{27}{4}=6.75$$
$$PQ=6.75m$$
You need not solve for $y$ as all we need is $PQ$

Answer (score 1):

Going from the Pythagoras's theorem:
as both PRT and PSQ are right triangles you can use it. So:
for small triangle $PRT$:
$$x^2+y^2=11^2$$
for big triangle $PSQ$:
$$x^2+(y+2)^2=12^2$$
Hence, $y = 19/4$
Finally, $PQ= 19/4+2=6.75$

Comment: What is length PQ

Comment: What is y In terms of

Comment: y=PT, x=RT=SQ,y+2=PQ

Comment: The question says "$PS$ is $12$"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\overline{TR}$ intersects $\overline{PS}$ at point $U$.

Use the law of cosines to determine the $\cos \measuredangle PSR$.

Then use the Pythagorean theorem to determine the sides of $\Delta RSU$.

Finally, show that $\Delta RSU \sim \Delta QPS$, then find $\overline{PQ}$